# Массив из функции

Tags: php

Как из этой функции вытащить массив `$data`?

```
function kv_euro()
{
    $path = CACHE_DIR . 'weather_' . weather_city('city') . '.json';

    $json = get_cache_value($path);
    if (false !== $json) {
        echo "";
        $data = json_decode($json);    
//echo $json;
    } else {

        $BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily"; //city
        //$yql_query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid="' . weather_city('id') . '"';


        $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?id=" . weather_city('id') . "&APPID=9e2227183d6b7351f6942dbaac4d24af";
// Make call with cURL
        $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($session);
        $data = json_decode($json);

        set_cache_value($path, $json);

    }  
}
```

Ставлю `return $data`, но всеравно не видит.

```
<?php print_r($data) ?>
```

Comment: а так? `<?php print_r(kv_euro()) ?>` и `return $data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все упирается в то, что вы подразумеваете под "вытащить массив"... В любом случае, чтобы его получить, нужно его вернуть:

```
function kv_euro()
{
    $path = CACHE_DIR . 'weather_' . weather_city('city') . '.json';
    $data = [];
    $json = get_cache_value($path);
    if (false !== $json) {
        echo "";
        $data = json_decode($json, true);    
//echo $json;
    } else {

        $BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily"; //city
        //$yql_query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid="' . weather_city('id') . '"';


        $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?id=" . weather_city('id') . "&APPID=9e2227183d6b7351f6942dbaac4d24af";
// Make call with cURL
        $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($session);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        set_cache_value($path, $json);

    }  
    return $data;
}
```

У себя пишите:

```
$data = kv_euro();
```

А если на экран вывести, то: `print '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы функция вернула данные переменной `$data` используйте `return`

```
function kv_euro()
{
    // тут ваш код
    // $data = json_decode($json);
    return $data;
}

$data = kv_euro();
// Вот и вытащили $data
// В вашем случае $data равняется объекту или NULL
```

`json_decode` по умолчанию возвращает `объект` или `NULL` в случае ошибки. Если вы хотите получить массив передайте вторым параметром `true`

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function kv_euro() 
{
    $data = [];
    //some code
    if() { //какой-то код 
        $data = json_decode($someVar);
    }
    else {//some other code
        $data = json_decode($someVar);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Примерно об этом Вам говорит @PinkTux

Answer (score -1):

Почитайте про область видимости переменных.

```
/* здесь пока никакой переменной $data нет */
if (false !== $json) {
  /* создалась переменная $data, локальная для этого блока */
  $data = json_decode($json);    
  /* и тут она уже пропала */
} else {
  /* создалась ДРУГАЯ переменная $data, локальная для этого блока */
  $data = json_decode($json);
  /* и тут она тоже пропала */
}  
/* и здесь никакой переменной $data нет */
```

Либо возвращайте `$data` внутри каждого блока отдельно (не самый хороший вариант), либо объявляйте эту переменную ДО использования внутри блоков `if/else`.

Comment: почему не самый хороший вариант?

Comment: Потому что никакого разумного обоснования для нескольких точек выхода из функции в данном случае нет.

Comment: ну почему же? сделали быструю проверку и вернули результат, а если уж проверка не прошла делаем что-то дальше, убирается лишний else, вложенность кода меньше становится например, проблема с областями видимости уходит вообще

Comment: Ну, переписать код - другой вопрос, тогда может и проще, и наглядней получится :)

Comment: Вложенность кода никак не меняется, в его объем увеличится, уважаемый @Grundy

Comment: @Hlogeon, каким образом увеличится если уберется блок else, а `$data =` заменится на `return`?

Comment: Это только в том случае, если никаких манипуляций над `$data` больше не предполагается производить, а такое бывает далеко не всегда. Лишний блок else Вы можете убрать только в том случае, если он не имеет никакого смысла, а смысл он, судя по всему все же имеет. Конечно, убирая функционал из функции можно ее сократить и повысить читабельность, но ведь это совсем не то, о чем мы здесь разговариваем, не так ли?

Comment: Короче говоря, если говорить именно о той функции, что приведена в примере, то лучший вариант - объявить переменную ДО блока if

Comment: Что за бред в примере написан? Всё отрабатывает на ура. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5c78b6e48608c829b305d39488d2f5f0cb7fab0

Comment: Если некая переменная была объявленна внутри блоков if, for etc. это не означает, что ее область видимости - тело этого блока. В php сборщик мусора работает не так, он освобождает память, после отработки метода (функции), но не после выполнения каждого блока инструкций. Описаное вами поведение было характерно для старых (действительно старых, стоит сказать, и не всех) компиляторов c++, там действительно можно было встретить подобное.